# Conditionally change color of table data Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to be able to highlight a specific td if a certain condition is met.

```
<tr *ngFor="let prospect of deployment">
                    <td>{{prospect.campaignName}} | {{prospect.campaignId}}</td>
                    <td>{{prospect.dealerName}} | {{prospect.dealerId}}</td>                
                    <td class="group-added">{{prospect.addedDate | date : 'shortDate' }}</td>
                    <td class="group-added" style="text-align: right;">{{prospect.addedProspects | number}}</td>
                    <td class="group-processed">{{prospect.startedDate | date : 'shortDate' }}</td>
                    <td class="group-processed">{{prospect.stage}}</td>                
                    <td class="group-processed" style="text-align: right;">{{prospect.processedProspects | number}}</td>
                    <td class="group-processed" style="text-align: right;">{{prospect.emailsSent | number}}</td>
                    <td class="group-processed" style="text-align: right;">{{prospect.emailsError | number}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf="perms.has(perms.CREATIVE) && prospect.bundleId != 0 && prospect.bundleId != null" style="text-align: right;">
                        <a [href]="'bundles/' + prospect.bundleId + '/assets'">Creative</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

I want to highlight the entire row in red where prospect.processedProspects is greater than 100 and the amount of sent emails for that prospect is less than 50%. I'm not sure if I can complete this using interpolation and class binding alone.

```
export class DeploymentSummaryScreen implements OnInit {

    loading: boolean;

    deployment: Deployment[];
    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date;
```

Not sure if more of the .ts file is needed.

Comment: I think you should give some more details on how you can get the data about the sentMails percentage. How is your data exactly (examples would be welcome) ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `[ngClass]` for doing this and assign  a class to table row.
The `NgClass` directive allows you to set the CSS class dynamically for a DOM element.
You need to write css for your `css-class` that serves your purpose:

```
<tr [ngClass]="{'font-red': prospect.processedProspects > 10" *ngFor="let prospect of deployment">
                    <td>{{prospect.campaignName}} | {{prospect.campaignId}}</td>
                    <td>{{prospect.dealerName}} | {{prospect.dealerId}}</td>                
                    <td class="group-added">{{prospect.addedDate | date : 'shortDate' }}</td>
                    <td class="group-added" style="text-align: right;">{{prospect.addedProspects | number}}</td>
                    <td class="group-processed">{{prospect.startedDate | date : 'shortDate' }}</td>
                    <td class="group-processed">{{prospect.stage}}</td>                
                    <td class="group-processed" style="text-align: right;">{{prospect.processedProspects | number}}</td>
                    <td class="group-processed" style="text-align: right;">{{prospect.emailsSent | number}}</td>
                    <td class="group-processed" style="text-align: right;">{{prospect.emailsError | number}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf="perms.has(perms.CREATIVE) && prospect.bundleId != 0 && prospect.bundleId != null" style="text-align: right;">
                        <a [href]="'bundles/' + prospect.bundleId + '/assets'">Creative</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

in css:

```
     .font-red { color: red; }
```

You can also use `NgStyle` directive which lets you set a given DOM elements style properties.
Ex:

```
  <tr [ngStyle]="{'background-color': prospect.processedProspects > 10 ? 'green' : 'red' }">
    ......
</<tr>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this answers the question in its entirety. I am targeting processedProspects that are greater than 100. I want to highlight these prospects where emailsSent is less than 50%.

Comment: @LDB : Then you should at least give some more information on how your emailsSent data is. Is it a integer between 0 and 100 ? is it a decimal number between 0 and 1 ? etc...

Comment: @LDB: you should try above approach to achieve your solution, we can't write the full code unless entire details are provided. also do not expect to get complete code. Based on your minimum reproducible code snippet, the answer is provided.

Comment: If you need to calculate percentage and make decision to style row on that, you can use function call to achieve that. `[ngClass]="{'font-red': getEmailSentPercentage() >10 "`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*ngClass` to apply a class conditionaly.

```
<tr *ngFor="let prospect of deployment"
    *ngClass="{specialHighlight: prospect.processedProspects > 10 && yourConditionOnEmails}">
```

and of course the `specialHighlight` class is to be defined somehow in your css.

Comment: yes you can access your `*ngFor` variable directly in the same tag's attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngClass] to achieve that. Following is my code, which is tested and working fine. Following sample use Material Icon as an example. So you must include following line in the *app.module.ts*.

`import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';`

Include following line in the *index.html*:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

In your html file:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

<!-- description Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="description">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Description </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"
  [ngClass]="{'specialHighlight': readIcon == 'mail'}"> {{element.description}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- trash Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="trash">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
  
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <span>
    <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon" (click)="changeRead()">{{ readIcon }}</mat-icon>
  </span>
  </td>
</ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
    (click)="rowClicked(row)">
</tr>
```

In your ts file:

```
/* readIcon indicates if the row (mail) is read */
readIcon = 'drafts';

changeRead() {
  if (this.readIcon == 'drafts') this.readIcon = 'mail';
  else this.readIcon = 'drafts';
```

}

In your css file:

```
.specialHighlight {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```